# How can I find a specific node in my XML?

Tags: c#, xml, nodes

I have to read the xml node "name" from the following XML, but I don't know how to do it.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
  <games>
    <game>
      <name>Google Pacman</name>
      <url>http:\\www.google.de</url>
    </game>
  </games>
```

Code:

```
using System.Xml;

namespace SRCDSGUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(Application.StartupPath + @"\games.xml");


            XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("//games");

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(node["game"].InnerText);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you need to read only the "name" node contents, make your XPath go directly to the text of those nodes: `/games/game/name/text()`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Maybe try this

```
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("//games/game")
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(node["name"].InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Or try this:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = root.GetElementsByTagName("name");
for(int i=0; i<nodes.Count; i++)
{
listBox1.Items.Add(nodes[i].InnerXml);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are really close - you found the game node, why don't you go a step further and just get the name node if it exists as a child under game?

in your for each loop:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(node.SelectSingleNode("game/name").InnerText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of simple function that finds and fetches two particular nodes from XML file and returns them as string array

```
private static string[] ReadSettings(string settingsFile)
    {
        string[] a = new string[2];
        try
        {
            XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(settingsFile);
            while (xmlReader.Read())
            {
                switch (xmlReader.Name)
                {
                    case "system":
                        break;
                    case "login":
                        a[0] = xmlReader.ReadString();
                        break;
                    case "password":
                        a[1] = xmlReader.ReadString();
                        break;
                }

            }    
            return a;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return a;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree= ET.parse('name.xml')
root= tree.getroot()

print root[0][0].text
```

- root = games
- root[0] = game
- root[0][0] = name
- root[0][1] = url
- use the ".text" to get string representation of value
- this example is using python